# Migration from Clearcase to Team Foundation Server

Tags: version-control, tfs, clearcase

We are considering moving from ClearCase to Team Foundation Server. The project is on Unix platform and fairly large - around 10 mln lines of C++ code.

I am curious if there is someone that has done similar migration.

•Are tools available for ClearCase to Team Foundation Server migration?

•Can Team Foundation Server be deployed on Unix platform?

•What are the prerequisites for such migration?

•Will Team Foundation Server be able to handle such a large project?

•Does it make sense to migrate all historical versions/branches?

Comment: Why Team Foundation Server if you are going to use Unix?

Comment: Cost is major factor for moving from Clearcase to TFS.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any official tool (as mentioned in "[About IBM Rational ClearCase and Microsoft Team Foundation Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21228699)".

The [TFS system requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253078%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) are clear: no Linux.
Even though you can explore those data from a "[Team Explorer Everywhere](http://ericdboyd.com/2011/04/03/microsoft-embraces-os-x-linux-and-unix-developers/)" on Unix, Linux, Mac.

---

[Spence](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53771/spence) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557216/migration-from-clearcase-to-team-foundation-server/11557953#comment28327814_11557953) that TFS now (early 2013) supports git (as I [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15129629/6309)), meaning you can have a TFS server on Windows, and git repos on Linux.

Comment: Note that for a migration, it is rare to migrate *all* the history. Only the latest baselines are exported, and ClearCase is kept around in a read-only mode for archive and history exploration.

Comment: I think this answer is now out of date based on the fact that GIT is supported out of the box now.  Combined with the web tools to drive the SCM/work items and GIT integration for branching linux + TFS is a perfectly good environment now.

Comment: @Spence I agree, and I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

"Does it make sense to migrate all historical versions/branches?" Generally no. Too much of a hassle, considering there is no official migration tool and your project is large. You can migrate several major history releases and the newest versions to TFS. In the meantime, keep the current Clearcase server running for another several months, in case your developers ever need to check the history.

"Will Team Foundation Server be able to handle such a large project?" personally i believe tfs is robust.