# How do I move a solution from git to tfs

Tags: git, visual-c++, tfs, migration

I decided to share a solution with a fellow programmer. We both have permissions to add to and work on projects in a shared Team Foundation Server.

I mistakenly created it in Git, and it is now only local to myself.

I don't know and don't wish to waste time now finding out, how to set up the git so it would be shared. I don't have permissions to put anything up on a shared server. Only via the TFS.

So: Is there an easy way to simply "move" the solution from Git up to the TFS.
Or do I have to remove the solution completely from Git (how? and is that complicated?) and then Add to Source Control and this time correctly to TFS?

I know I'm going in the opposite direction from everyone else. But that's what will work easiest for me... unless making the Git repo available to both of us can be done in an extremely fast way, without need for any admin permissions from myself.

Thank you

Comment: I cannot use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128541/how-can-i-push-my-existing-git-repository-to-team-foundation-service because it is creating a new project in Team Server which, if I understand correctly only done with admin permissions in Team Server. I want to add the solution to an existing team project which both of us see and under which we have several shared solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just copy the files from your GIT repo to your TFVC repo.

If you map your TFVC repo to a local folder and copy the contents of your GIT repo into out to can simply check in the code.

Note: You can create team projects in TFS that support either TFVC or GIT as the source control system. This is a choice when the team project is created and currently can't be changed later.

Comment: I'll try this, and if it works, will mark it as answer.

I know that you can either support tfvc or git. According to what I read somewhere I thought I can do both. Git for my local merges until the fast forward and then TFVC for sharing with the team. 

That is why I created it as a Git project in the first place. Then found that I was not able to share it with other team members (we both are not the admins of the TFS or any other shared server).